# Convert Db2 Procedure to Oracle Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, db2

I'm trying to migrate procedures from db2 database to oracle I have more than 30 procedure there are any conversion tools can help this process?

For example, I have this procedure in db2 return **DYNAMIC RESULT SETS** how can rewrite the equvlent   procedure in oracle

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GET_Data (
    IN P_DATA_1 VARCHAR(4),
    IN P_DATA_2 VARCHAR(4) )
  SPECIFIC SQL4234234343442343
  DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
  LANGUAGE SQL
  NOT DETERMINISTIC
  EXTERNAL ACTION
  MODIFIES SQL DATA
  CALLED ON NULL INPUT
  INHERIT SPECIAL REGISTERS
  OLD SAVEPOINT LEVEL
P1: BEGIN
    -- Declare cursorf
    DECLARE RESULT_SET1 CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CLIENT FOR 
        SELECT DATA_NAME, DATA_VALUE1,DATA_VALUE2
        FROM Data
        WHERE DATA_VALUE1 = P_DATA_1 AND DATA_VALUE2 = P_DATA_2;


    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Data WHERE DATA_VALUE1 = P_DATA_1 AND DATA_VALUE2 = P_DATA_2) 
        THEN                  
           OPEN RESULT_SET1;
        ELSE 
            RETURN;
    END IF;
END P1;
```

This Sample conversion :

```
-- SQLINES LICENSE FOR EVALUATION USE ONLY
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_Data (
    P_DATA_1 IN VARCHAR2,
    P_DATA_2 IN VARCHAR2 )
  IS 
BEGIN
  OLD
/ SAVEPOINT LEVEL
<<P1>> BEGIN
    -- Declare cursorf


    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Data WHERE DATA_VALUE1 = P_DATA_1 AND DATA_VALUE2 = P_DATA_2) 
        THEN                  
           OPEN RESULT_SET1 FOR 
        SELECT DATA_NAME, DATA_VALUE1,DATA_VALUE2
        FROM Data
        WHERE DATA_VALUE1 = P_DATA_1 AND DATA_VALUE2 = P_DATA_2;
        ELSE 
            RETURN;
    END IF;
END P1;
```

Comment: Can you please post your attempts, explaining what's wrong with your code.

Comment: @Aleksej I update the questions, in db2 the return type resultset but this type does not exist in oracle I want to keep the return type result set it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

You probably looking for SYS_REFCURSOR. If you are using Oracle Version 11g or older, You can try below code -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_Data (
    P_DATA_1 IN VARCHAR2,
    P_DATA_2 IN VARCHAR2,
    RESULT_SET1 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
  IS 
BEGIN
    -- Declare cursorf

    OPEN RESULT_SET1 FOR 
         SELECT DATA_NAME, DATA_VALUE1,DATA_VALUE2
           FROM Data
          WHERE DATA_VALUE1 = P_DATA_1
            AND DATA_VALUE2 = P_DATA_2;
END GET_Data;
```

From 12c onwards, You can use DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT for implicit cursor return as below -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_Data (
    P_DATA_1 IN VARCHAR2,
    P_DATA_2 IN VARCHAR2)
  IS 
BEGIN
    -- Declare cursorf

    OPEN RESULT_SET1 FOR 
         SELECT DATA_NAME, DATA_VALUE1,DATA_VALUE2
           FROM Data
          WHERE DATA_VALUE1 = P_DATA_1
            AND DATA_VALUE2 = P_DATA_2;

    DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(RESULT_SET1);

END GET_Data;
```

Then you can execute this procedure to get the result.

Comment: Thank you for your response, our Oracle version it's  9 it's possible to return SYS_REFCURSOR without out parameter because if I change the signature procedure need also to change in code that calling this procedure so any suggestions?

Comment: First of all, you must upgrade your version, and secondly, there is no such way to return SYS_REFCURSOR without changing the definition.